# Why can't browser find java plugin?

Tags: java, windows, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

There are computers running Windows 8.1 x64 with installed Java Development environment JDK & JRE, which works properly. But when trying to run java-applets in the browser, browser occurs 'Java plugin not found' error' How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed plugin updated but I face issue at testing time plugin not work properly in Chrome using link http://java.com/en/download/installed8.jsp?detect=jre If you got message "This plug-in is not supported" then follow following steps: 
In your URL bar, enter:

1. chrome://flags/#enable-npapi
2. Click the Enable link for the Enable NPAPI configuration option.
3. Click the Relaunch button that now appears at the bottom of the
   configuration page.

and test it again using http://java.com/en/download/installed8.jsp?detect=jre link.

Answer (score 2):

Java is not enabled in the web browser. If Java is already installed but applets do not work, you need to enable Java through your web browser.

**Internet Explorer**

```
Click Tools and then Internet Options
Select the Security tab, and select the Custom Level button
Scroll down to Scripting of Java applets
Make sure the Enable radio button is checked
Click OK to save your preference
```

**Chrome**

```
Enter about:plugins in the search field.
In the Plug-ins list, look for Java and check whether Java is enabled (if the Disable link appears, Java is already enabled)
Click on the Enable link (if available)
(Optional) Check the Always allowed box to stop additional Chrome warnings when running Java content
```

see [How do I enable Java in my web browser?](https://java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser.xml)

Comment: But there is not java plugin in list

Comment: @skeeph Type chrome://plugins/ in chrome address bar and press enter

Comment: I did it, but there not Java plugin